# Flink Watermark forBoundedOutOfOrderness includes data beyond boundaries

Tags: apache-flink

I'm assigning timestamps and watermarks like this

```
def myProcess(dataStream: DataStream[Foo]) { 
  dataStream
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
      WatermarkStrategy
        .forBoundedOutOfOrderness[Foo](Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .withTimestampAssigner(new SerializableTimestampAssigner[Foo]() {
          // Long is milliseconds since the Epoch
          override def extractTimestamp(element: Foo, recordTimestamp: Long): Long = element.eventTimestamp
        })  
    )
    .keyBy({ k => k.id
    })
    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.hours(1)))
    .reduce(new MyReducerFn(), new MyWindowFunction())
  }
```

I have a unit test

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env.setParallelism(1)
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)


val dataTime = 1641488400000L
val lateTime = dataTime + Duration.ofHours(5).toMillis
val dataSource = env
  .addSource(new SourceFunction[Foo]() {
    def run(ctx: SourceFunction.SourceContext[Foo]) {
      ctx.collect(Foo(id=1, value=1, eventTimestamp=dataTime))
      ctx.collect(Foo(id=1, value=1, eventTimestamp=lateTime))
      // should be dropped due to past max lateness
      ctx.collect(Foo(id=1, value=2, eventTimestamp=dataTime))
    }

    override def cancel(): Unit = {}
  })

myProcess(dataSource).collect(new MyTestSink)
env.execute("watermark & lateness test")
```

I expect that the second element would advance the watermark to (latetime - Duration.ofSeconds(5)) (i.e. the bounded out of orderness) and therefore the third element would not be assigned to the 1 hour tumbling window since the watermark had advanced considerably past it.  However I see both the first and third element reach my reduce function.

I must misunderstand watermarks here?  Or what forBoundedOutOfOrderness does?  Can I please get clarity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I must have typo'd something I have it working.